# Appending and Filtering divs from external HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Hello everyone I started learning a little coding and I'm making a project for my course to make my life a little easier with info and other data.

now I made a single HTML and made 2 other external HTML's in the Appends folder and I use them to append a `div` `#AD` to the original html `#wrapper` `div`.

My problem is is that it works perfectly fine when there is a single `div` inside the whole HTML and if I want to remove the 2 HTMLs and unify them together and put 2 divs inside single external HTML it just doesn't work I searched some info and tried various things using find and filter but it just doesn't work and I can't understand why and what am I doing wrong.

I have this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "appends/ADDiv.html",
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (data) { 
        $('#wrapper').append(data); 
    }
});
```

This is the original code I have that works and it appends the `div` that is inside the external html to the wrapper without any problems but if I add 2 divs they just stop working.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the divs are appended using a menu when u press AD menu a related Div appends and when u press CS menu a div appends related to that topic

EDIT2:

Ok, I forgot to show what I got hehe sorry so my codes goes like this:

index

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:showAD();">AD</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:showCS();">CS</a></li>
</ul>

<div id='wrapper'> </div>
```

and in my External html I have divs with buttons to test what works and what not :P

```
<div id='AD'>
   <input type="button" value="Generate"/></td>
</div>

<div id='CS'>
   <input type="button" value="Generate2"/></td>
</div>
```

The recent code I tried was this and it kind of works if I point it to my second div it appends 1 `div` if i point it to my first div it appends all the divs

```
$.ajax({
dataType: 'html',
success: function (data) {                  
    $('#wrapper').append($('<div>').load('appends/ADDiv.html #AD')); },
});
```

Comment: `they just stop working` any errors in console? Make sure that id should be unique.

Comment: I think you should post the unworking code not the working one

Comment: better to post your markup and links too.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you should use `.load(url, data, callback)` method to load the external particular div.

as per edit2:

```
  $('ul li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#wrapper').load("addDiv.html " + page);
  });
```

### [Updated Plnkr Demo.](http://plnkr.co/edit/FMGfkuSwd7V75bbqBS3d?p=preview)

Comment: i tried the idea u gave me last time :P i learned something new lol but for some reason i need to click twice for the content to show lol maybe because of the href?